# How python time module calculate the value of daylight?

Tags: python

OS : Windows 7, 8.0 or 8.1

One of the Computer in Eastern TimeZone has set a daylight option.
It's time.daylight value shown to me is 69. 
Yes, daylight is defined, time.localtime().tm_dst is returning correct to 1.

When I check time.daylight python docs, it only mentioned that,

> `time.daylight` 
>   Nonzero if a DST timezone is defined.

I have tried changing time with almost every time zone in the list. But 
always I got value of time.daylight to 1 only.

Is there any way to produce time.daylight value to greater than 1 ?

Any help would be appreciated ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what are you looking for. As the docs say `time.daylight` just indicates whether the system has some DST timezone configured or not, so it’s just a “yes”/“no” value. What do you expect to it to be if it is greater than `1`?

Are you looking for [`time.altzone`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.altzone) which contains the offset of DST in case one is defined?

Comment: Are you sure, time.daylight is yes/no only (i.e. 0/1 or 1+ ) because I didn't able to produce value other than 1 and .5.

                                                                                                                It also return .5 when time-zone supports half hour daylight saving.
Basically It is 1 for those countries using 1 hour daylight saving time and .5 for those countries using half hour daylight saving time.
So, the question was, I am getting time.daylight value to 69 on some computers in Easter Timezone those who enabled daylight, why so ?

Comment: @user3016020 You quoted the doc yourself, it is either _zero_ or _nonzero_. Just two options: yes or no. Nothing else is guaranteed. The exact value probably depends on the OS and some other details, but its meaning is undefined.

Answer (score -1):

It is strange that it uses an integer and not just a True / False boolean, but it does appear to just be a flag. Check `help(time)` and you'll see:

```
daylight -- whether local time should reflect DST
```

I don't know where the 69 is coming from, but I think you should just take it to mean non-zero. As kirelagin suggests, you should us time.altzone to find the DST offset.

Because you're only supposed to use time.altzone if time.daylight is nonzero, you could use one of the following to get the DST offset in hours:

```
dst_offset = time.daylight and time.altzone/60/60
dst_offset = time.altzone/60/60 if time.daylight else 0
```

Comment: This is incorrect, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49573065/634919.