# Why Python's time.timezone returns wrong offset seconds?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

Why Python's time.timezone returns wrong offset seconds?

I'm working on two servers located in different time zones. The time zone settings of both the servers seem good (please ignore the slight time difference between the two server):

Out put of 'date' command on the server in China (China Standard Time, UTC+8):

```
$ date ; date -u ; date '+%Z (%:::z)'
Fri Mar 30 17:52:06 CST 2018
Fri Mar 30 09:52:06 UTC 2018
CST (+08)
```

Out put of 'date' command on the server in U.S.A. (Central Daylight Time, UTC-5):

```
$ date ; date -u ; date '+%Z (%:::z)'
Fri Mar 30 04:56:52 CDT 2018
Fri Mar 30 09:56:52 UTC 2018
CDT (-05)
```

**BUT** when I use Python's time.timezone to get the offset seconds, it returns wrong number for the U.S. server but correct with China:

Python running result on China server (correct time.timezone):

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov  6 2016, 00:28:07)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from datetime import datetime as dt
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> import time
>>> print dt.now()
2018-03-30 17:45:51.661311
>>> print dt.utcnow()
2018-03-30 09:45:51.661738
>>> print time.timezone
-28800  # This is -8 hours
>>> utc_time_delta = timedelta(seconds=time.timezone) ; print utc_time_delta;
-1 day, 16:00:00
>>>
```

Python running result on U.S.A. server (**incorrect** time.timezone):

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from datetime import datetime as dt
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> import time
>>> print dt.now()
2018-03-30 04:50:36.261980
>>> print dt.utcnow()
2018-03-30 09:50:36.262212
>>> print time.timezone
21600  # This is +6 hours (incorrect)
>>> utc_time_delta = timedelta(seconds=time.timezone) ; print utc_time_delta;
6:00:00
>>>
```

Why it happens like this? Is it something wrong with daylight time and standard time?

Furthermore, how can I display the datetime value in a human readable format with specific timezone offset without pytz? (I'm not the administrator of that server so I cannot install pytz)

The reason I use time.timezone is that I want to read a epoch number (by convention, it is always in UTC), then print it in both local U.S.A. time and China time.

```
>>> time_epoch_str = '1522401308'
>>> time_dt = dt.fromtimestamp(int(time_epoch_str))
>>> utc_time_delta = timedelta(seconds=time.timezone)
>>> china_time_delta = utc_time_delta + timedelta(hours=8)
>>> print("U.S.A. time: %s; UTC time: %s; China time: %s" 
... % (time_dt, time_dt + utc_time_delta, time_dt + china_time_delta))
U.S.A. time: 2018-03-30 04:15:08; UTC time: 2018-03-30 10:15:08; China time: 2018-03-30 18:15:08
```

But it shows wrong result, the correct time of epoch 1522401308 is:

```
GMT: Friday, March 30, 2018 9:15:08 AM
Your time zone: Friday, March 30, 2018 5:15:08 PM GMT+08:00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get if the actual timezone of a time, you have to use "tm_dst" of a "time" instance.

The original edition of this answer suggests using "time.daylight", but this flag is constant and doesn't change. It tells whether the "altzone" (daylight saving time offset) is set, and once it's set, "time.daylight" is always "1", no matter whether the current time is daylight saving time or not.

To get the time correct time offset, you should use the following code:

```
t = time.localtime()
if t.tm_isdst == 0:
    tz_offset = time.timezone
else:
    tz_offset = time.altzone
```

**The following is the original answer:**

Hahaha, finally I found out what I missed. I should look at Python doc more carefully.

Check the following Python doc:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.altzone

It is indeed the issue of daylight saving time. I should change my code to:

```
if time.daylight == 0:
    utc_time_delta = timedelta(seconds=time.timezone)
else:
    utc_time_delta = timedelta(seconds=time.altzone)
```

"time.timezone" doesn't change automatically, but "time.daylight" changes.